# How to update version in package.json using calendar versioning

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, package.json, versioning, package-lock.json

Our intern project use calendar versioning for our angular typescript project managed with npm.

For example the version `2024.02.19.0` is for the first version of 19 february 2024.

However if I run `npm version 2024.02.19.0`, resulting version does not make any sense:

```
v2024.2.1-9.0
```

First of all "19" became "1-9" which does not make any sense. and "02" became "2", which ruins alphabetical order.

How do I update my version without npm messing with my version name.

Note: I could manually edit package.json, which is what we have done until now but we plan on scripting it in our GitlabCI. `nmp version` also has the courtesy of updating package-lock.json, which is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by not using npm version and instead relying on jq:

```
VERSION=2024.02.19.0
jq --arg v "$VERSION" '.version = $v' package.json > tmp.json && mv -f tmp.json package.json
jq --arg v "$VERSION" '.version = $v | .packages."".version = $v' package-lock.json > tmp.json && mv -f tmp.json package-lock.json
```

using a `tmp.json` buffer file to edit json 'inplace'